# Viewing JavaScript Console Output in Capybara

Tags: selenium-webdriver, console, capybara

I'm using `capybara` (`3.9.0`) with `selenium-webdriver` (`3.14.1`)

Is there an easy way to view the output printed to the browser console with `console.log()`, `console.debug()`, etc... ?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45168644/2490003) implies that I can do the following, which errors:

```
> page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)
NoMethodError: undefined method `log' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Bridge:0x00007fa4ae2d8a98>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be running a recent version of Capybara and selenium-webdriver for that to be available. You will also will need to configure your driver to enable logging in Chrome, otherwise the call will always return empty.